# Scroll to anchor on homepage from another page

Tags: jquery, wordpress, anchor

I have a Wordpress website with custom menu items:

- About has link `#about`
- Cities has link `#cities`
- Practical info goes to another page.

All the # links scroll to their specific block on the homepage. But when I'm on the practical info page, my URL is url.be/practical-info/ So when I try to click on "About", the URL is url.be/practical-info/#about and than obviously won't work.

My solution would be, if I click on a menu item with a # in it, add the website base URL in front of it? Or is there a better way to handle this issue?

I already got this in jQuery:

```
    //anchor links
    jQuery('a.nav-link[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {

        // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
      if (this.hash !== "") {

          // Store hash
          var hash = this.hash;

          // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
          // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
          }, 2000, function() {

            // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
            window.location.hash = hash;
          });
          return false;
      } // End if
    });
```

Or this is the for each that replaces the href values from the # links:

```
    jQuery("a[href^='\#']").each(function(){ 
        //this.href=location.href.split("#")[0]+'#'+this.href.substr(this.href.indexOf('#')+1);
        var getUrl = window.location;
        var baseurl = getUrl.origin;
        var hash = this.href.substr(this.href.indexOf('#')+1);
        var fullurl = baseurl + '#' + hash;

        this.attr('href', fullurl);
        console.log(this);
    });
```

But also this one doesn't work and throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the attribute to the wrong thing. jQuery's `$(this)` has a `.attr()` function, but the native `this` doesn't.

(I added a bit of CSS to the snippet to make it easier to see the example.)

```js
jQuery("a[href^='\#']").each(function() {
      var getUrl = window.location;
      var baseurl = getUrl.origin;
      var hash = this.href.substr(this.href.indexOf('#') + 1);
      var fullurl = baseurl + '#' + hash;
    
      $(this).attr('href', fullurl);
      // ^ needs to be $(this), not this. You can also use this.href = fullurl;  
    });
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
}
a[href*='#']:after {
  content: " (" attr(href) ")";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#about">About</a>
<a href="#contact">Contact</a>
<a href="other-stuff">Other Stuffs</a>
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error when I click on a navigation item: jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http://apereau.test#about

Comment: It's fixed. Another part of my scripted caused this error. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (window.location.hash)
    scroll(0,0);
setTimeout(function(){scroll(0,0);},1);

$(function(){
$('.scroll').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop:$($(this).attr('href')).offset().top + 'px'
    },1000,'swing');
});


if(window.location.hash){
    // smooth scroll to the anchor id
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop:$(window.location.hash).offset().top + 'px'
        },1000,'swing');
    }
});
```